After using concat and scale2ref filter only part of video is encoded
I'm trying to select some parts of an video, concat them, and apply an overlay that should have 1/6 of the video width:
ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -i "input.mp4" -t 12 -loop 1 -i flag.webp -an -filter_complex "[0]select='between(t,3,9)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[P1];[0]select='between(t,12,15)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[P2];[0]select='between(t,60,70)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[P3];[P1][P2][P3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[vid];[1][vid]scale2ref=w=iw/6:h=ow/mdar[flag][vid];[vid][flag]overlay=x=20:y=20:enable='between(t,1,7)'[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -b:v 900K -y "output.mp4"

The output video results in a video that contains only the first part of the selections [P1] (or even less)...
Strangly if I use something like this without using concat filter everything works like expected:
ffmpeg -reinit_filter 0 -i "input.mp4" -t 12 -loop 1 -i flag.webp -an -filter_complex "[0]select='between(t,3,9)+between(t,12,15)+between(t,60,70)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[vid];[1][vid]scale2ref=w=iw/6:h=ow/mdar[flag][vid];[vid][flag]overlay=x=20:y=20:enable='between(t,1,7)'[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -b:v 900K -y "output.mp4"

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to use concat with scale2ref and overlay together? Thanks...

It would be much easier to cut out the pieces first and then concat.  ffmpeg -i -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:00 -c copy -an output.mkv This cuts a the closest keyframe.  If you need cuts at exact times, you have to re-encode.  Swap -c copy for -preset ultrafast

There's a bug related to scale2ref in recent versions; try with <6.0

@Gyan where can I find this old versions?
